# Error on .ExecuteNonQuery() in SQL Update Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to update an Access database using a SQL query, whenever I click the save button, it generates an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

And highlights `.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Can you guys help me on this? I'm new to vb.net.

Thanks in advance.

```
 Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
        Dim empNum As String
        Dim empFname As String
        Dim empLname As String
        Dim empDept As String
        Dim empStat As String
        Dim empYears As String



        empNum = eNumText.Text
        empFname = empFnameText.Text
        empLname = empLnameText.Text
        empDept = DeptText.Text
        empStat = StatText.Text
        empYears = yearstext.Text

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= c:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"
        con.Open()

        MsgBox(empNum)


        Dim SqlAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim Table As New DataTable

        Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_empinfo SET EmpID='" & empNum & "', FirstName ='" & empFname & "', LastName='" & empLname & "', Department='" & empDept & "', Status='" & empStat & "', Years='" & empYears & "' WHERE EmpID ='" & empNum & "' "


        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, con)
            With cmd
                .CommandText = sqlQuery
                .Connection = con
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("EmpID", empNum)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", empFname)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", empLname)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("Department", empDept)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", empStat)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("Years", empYears)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        End Using

        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_empinfo "
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter


        With cmd1
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = con
            With SqlAdapter
                .SelectCommand = cmd1
                .Fill(Table)
            End With
            With DataGridView1
                .DataSource = Table
            End With
        End With

        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

your query syntax is wrong. Since you are using params, use placeholders in the SQL:  (the question marks are not some 'etc' type thing, you use `?` to mark parameters!):

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_empinfo SET FirstName = ?, 
             LastName=?, Department=?,
             Status=?, Years=? WHERE empID = ?"
```

Note: Six parameters

```
' USING will dispose of the cmd when it is done with it
' ...can also set the SQL and connection props in the constructor:
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, con)
   With cmd
       ' no reason to move Textboxes to a variable either:
       .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", empFnameText.Text)
       .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", empLnameText.Text)
       .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", DeptText.Text)
       .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", StatText.Text)
       .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", yearstext.Text)
```

your missing 6th parameter:

```
      .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", eNumText.Text)        
      .ExecuteNonQuery()
   End With
 End Using
```

I dont think Access supports named params, so you use dummy ones but be sure to `AddWithValue` in the order specified in the SQL string.

**EDIT**

You can just create a SQL string with the values embedded instead of using params which is *sort* of what your SQL string does.  Params are much better (research SQL injection attacks), but your string method is wrong (and you cant mix methods).  It should be:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_empinfo " & 
       "SET FirstName = " & empFname & ", LastName=" & empLname
```

The variables have to be outside the quotes or you will be setting `FirstName` to the literal "empFname"

Comment: i still get this erro "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters." highlights .ExecuteNonQuery() :(

Comment: make sure of the number of params in the SQL matches the number of AddWithValue statements you have and the order is correct.  If one of the Textboxes is empty, make sure the DB allows nulls on that column. `No value given for one or more required parameters` means what it says, you specified something the SQL that has no param value set.

Comment: i checked it's correct, is my SQL Statement correct using VB.NET and Access Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_empinfo " & _
        "SET FirstName=empFname, LastName=empLname, Department=empDept, " & _
        "Status=empStat, Years=empYears " & _
        "WHERE EmpID=empNum"       maybe it's coded differently, like is Amper Sign Accepted?

Comment: examine my answer closely...your SQL statement is still incorrect.  you mix parameters with an incorrect string concatenation form.  (comments do not format code, but you can edit your post to show updates/edits)

Comment: i tried your suggestion  Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_empinfo SET FirstName=empFname, LastName=empLname, Department=empDept, Status=empStat, Years=empYears WHERE EmpID=empNum" but still same error i am lost :(

Comment: examine my answer **closely** my SQL string looks nothing like that!  you need to use question marks to mark the parameters

Comment: You're building a `SELECT` statement which includes items such as *empFname*.  If those are the names of your VB.Net variables, the Access db engine won't know anything about them ... so assumes they must be parameters.  You would need to use the variables' *values* instead of their names.  But better to use a parameter query as Plutonix suggested.

Comment: i tried yours : Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_empinfo SET FirstName=empFname?, LastName=empLname?, Department=empDept?, Status=empStat?, Years=empYears? WHERE EmpID=empNum?"  Still same error  i don't understand why am i still getting an error :(

Comment: `SET FirstName=empFname? ...` is nothing like what I have: `SET FirstName = ?, LastName = ?, ...`  the db layer has no idea what "empFName" is or its value

Comment: i have followed parameters suggested above, i'm lost which paramater i lack. i'm really confused.

Comment: read my previous comment (or the EDIT to the answer) very very carefully - yours does not match mine - I do not use `empFName` **at all**. you have extra text in your SQL string

Comment: i have this exactly on my code, i don't think it makes sense Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_empinfo SET FirstName=?, LastName=?, Department=?, Status=?, Years=? WHERE EmpID=?"
and still gives me the same error, i can't understand at all

Comment: the `?` **are** the parm placeholders which are replaced using the `AddWithValue`  function. update your post with the current code but be sure you the names used in the SQL string are exactly those used in the database (FirstName vs empFName or some such).  Your original post is missing a parameter - count the `?` vs the `.AddWithValue` times - you do not set the `EmpNum` parameter for the WHERE clause  (easy to forget once until all records get changed)

Comment: this is what i have so far, i've set the corresponding needed parameter, i don't understand why it's still giving me the same error. :( it's so dificult http://i59.tinypic.com/icsk1d.png

Comment: look at my previous comment - refresh the page - you specify 6 params but only set 5 of them  `EmpID` is never set.  you need to EDIT your post HERE so the code is HERE.  The SQL string in the picture **is not** what you posted above and is **not** how it should be.

Comment: I have updated my codes above, i have followed your Advise and declared all parameters in my database. i have set the paramaters outside the " " (double quote) i still have the same error. what am i really missing here?

Comment: READ MY LAST FEW COMMENTS - you are still using the wrong SQL string and you **do not** have the correct number of parameters.  I am giving you the SAME CODE Steve did in your last question and you are ignoring everything you are given.  I updated my code to give a complete answer (no etc), try it out **as it is presented**.