# Using parameterized query, getting 'must declare scalar' error (adding binary file to a column in SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

I've been struggling all afternoon with trying to save a zip file in a `varbinary(MAX)` column in SQL Server. I think I've got the zip file saved as a binary array, but I just can't seem to get it saved to the database.

My connection:

```
Dim objConnection As OleDbConnection
Dim objCommand As OleDbCommand
objConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConn)
objConnection.Open()
```

Saving the zip file from disk to a binary array:

```
Dim filePath As String = Session("ZipFileName")
Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
br.Close()
fs.Close()
```

And then (trying to) save the file to my database:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET BinFile = @Data WHERE RecordID = '" & Session("RecName") & "'"
objCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConnection)
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes
objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I've been trying different variations of this idea for hours, including a handful from this site, but I keep getting the error

> Must declare the scalar variable '@Data'

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: that does not appear to be the correct syntax for `.AddWithValue`: `Parameters:
parameterName: The name of the parameter.
value: The value to be added.`  you are passing the DBType; there is no overload for your way.  you can pass the DBType in the Parameter constructor, but even then it is supposed to be an `OleDbType` not `SQLDbType`.  you are mixinf SQLClient (SQL Server) and OleDB (Access)

Comment: @Plutonix, thanks for your answer. This is actually one of many, many variations I've tried - your right, this one was for 'ADD', but Web Developer Studio is telling me that 'ADD' is deprecated. Can you clue me in on what syntax I SHOULD be using?

Comment: Even though you are using parameters, this code is still vulnerable to Sql Injection attack because of the way you are specifying the RecordID.

Comment: you didnt tag this as Web based, so I am going by MSDN and Winforms, but if the DB is SQL Server, you should probably be using `SqlClient` not `OleDB`.  see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23186186/1070452) for using OleDB version.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, if I can get this parameterization thing going I'll change that too. I was just trying to simplify the problem. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm under the gun to get this project out the door so I can't change now, but I'll follow your advice in future projects (dump OleDB, teach myself SqlClient). Again, any advice on syntax that might work for me here? Thanks again.

Comment: the answer is in the link I provided - that is how OleDB works with params, syntax, SQL format and all.  SQLClient works much the same, just import a different DB layer.  you almost certainly are already importing `SQlClient` or `SqlDbType` would be unresolved.

Comment: Plutonix, I did everything in your link except change @data to '?'. Works great now, thanks so much for all your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

As Plutonix suggests, your use of `AddWithValue` is incorrect.  The whole point of `AddWithValue` is that you provide the name and value and the rest is inferred.  The way you're calling it is what you would do with `Add` rather than `AddWithValue`, i.e. specify the type of the parameter yourself and then set the `Value` property afterwards.  `AddWithValue` exists specifically so that you don;t have to do that.

Also, given that you are already doing the right thing and using a parameter for the `BinFile` column, why then break the rules and use string concatenation for the `RecordID`?  Just do the right thing again and use parameters for both.

Comment: thanks for your reply. As I told Plutonix, this is one of many variations I've been working on, and yes, once I get this thing off the ground I will add a second parameter for the string I'm concatenating - I was just trying to simplify my problem. Can you suggest code that you think would work? I've looked at forums, blobs, and the MSDN, but I'm really stuck.